# How do I add Stripe Subscription Payments into ASP.NET Blazor webassembly?

Tags: stripe-payments, blazor, blazor-server-side, webassembly

I'm looking at [this Stripe client side code](https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-subscription-and-add-on/tree/master/client) that has a javascript and HTML to include in a Blazor application.

What is the best way to do this? Am I still concerned about startup times with a progressive web app, and could load the Stripe code in the index.html, and let it be live during the whole app?

Is there a more efficient way to include this (small) JS code in a Blazor webassembly client?

*PS if stripe people are reading, function app web hooks or other solutions would be helpful if in .NET

Comment: I am not an expert in Blazor, but I think the starting point might be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-3.1 
Just treat stripe.js as any other JavaScript library and you could call the function through Blazor WebAssembly JS Interop
Again, not offering answer here but there is another resource https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DLS3WflbGE

Comment: were you able to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are going to use stripe element payment method.
follow these links :

https://albertromkes.com/2020/02/08/integrating-blazor-webassembly-with-stripe/
https://github.com/bradwellsb/blazor-stripe